# how to include a private local file in javascript project using bower

Tags: javascript, bower

i want to include a custom file as one of the bower dependency.

I am have the following bower.json

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "sass-bootstrap": "~2.3.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.4",
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "beautify": "file:/path/to/beautify.js"
  },

  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

But when i do bower install 
it gives error :

```
 bower beautify#*             ENOTFOUND Package file:/path/to/beautify.js not found
```

however when i open the same path in browser i get the right file.
I have also checked the case sensitive of the path.

Now can any one tell me what error i am doing? Is there any thing wrong with the syntax?

Also tell me what if i want to add the same via bower cache. Where the global bower cache is stored in mac? And how can we register the url of private package so that i just need to put name of the package in `bower.json` and bower finds the file from the cache?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code below didn't work for me using Bower 1.2.8 on Ubuntu.

`"beautify": "/path/to/beautify.js"`

What did work was using: `"beautify": "./path/to/beautify.js"`. This way the path is pointing to the file relative from the directory where bower.json resides.

Comment: I would assume "path/to/beautify.js" would also work.  I believe a leading '/' signals that you have an absolute url.

Comment: @Teepeemm Probably, but the dot in front of '/' indicates the current directory.

Comment: @Teepeemm Didn't work :/ Only `./path/to/beautify.js`

Answer (score 5):

It should be just /relative/path/to/beautify.js. No 'file:/'.

```
"beautify": "/path/to/beautify.js"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have bower installed you can do this from the commandline

```
bower install ../beautify.js -S
```

Assuming the local repo is a directory next to your current directory. This is just a testing approach and should be an available repo for general use

---

EDIT

It looks like you also need to tag your repo so you will pick up the latest changes too

```
git tag v0.0.2
```