# how to include a local javascript im ember-cli application

Tags: ember-cli

I have a local javascript in my application that i want to include in my ember-cli application.

it is called carrotsearch.foamtree.js

In order that it will be included i put it under vendor\foamtree\carrotsearch.foamtree
and in the app.js i write

`import CarrotSearchFoamTree from 'foamtree/carrotsearch.foamtree'`

the problem is that i get an error

> ===== 1 JSHint Error
>
> Build failed. ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-37cYqLzL.tmp\foamtree\carrotsearch.foamtree.js'
>
> File: foamtree/carrotsearch.foamtree.js Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-37cYqLzL.tmp\foamtree\carrotsearch.foamtree.js'
>
> at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:689:18)   at addModule
>   (C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-cli\no
>   de_modules\broccoli-es6-concatenator\index.js:83:46)   at addModule
>   (C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-cli\no
>   de_modules\broccoli-es6-concatenator\index.js:126:9)   at
>   C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\
>   broccoli-es6-concatenator\index.js:59:7   at tryCatch
>   (C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-cli\nod
>   e_modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp-internal.js:163:16)   at
>   invokeCallback
>   (C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-c
>   li\node_modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp-internal.js:172:17)   at
>   publish
>   (C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-cli\node
>   _modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp-internal.js:150:13)   at flush (C:\Users\davidga\Desktop\ember\nextgen\node_modules\ember-cli\node_m
>   odules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp\asap.js:51:9)   at
>   process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

I thought that the problem is maybe bower related so i followed the following post [how to include a private local file in javascript project using bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317105/how-to-include-a-private-local-file-in-javascript-project-using-bower)

The problem is that neither 
"foamtree": "foamtree/carrotsearch.foamtree.js"

nor

"foamtree": "vendor/foamtree/carrotsearch.foamtree.js"

works.

What may i do?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer.

In brocfile.js we can add the line

```
app.import('vendor/foamtree/carrotsearch.foamtree.js')
```

I don't know if this is an optimal anser but it works

Update:

This solution is stated in the ember-cli documentation

http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#managing-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need them to minified in your vendor.js file you can put them in the `public/js` and then include it as a normal script file in `app/index.html`. I use this method for some libraries like moment.js.

The `public` folder gets directly copied to your site root during the build.