# How to handle custom libraries in a bower project?

Tags: bower

I have used bower before. But this time I need to add a commercial javascript library whose license I purchased online.

It seems to be the kind of library you would add with bower, but this one is not contained in any repository so it can't be pulled with bower. It must be added manually.

How should I structure my folder structure so it still makes sense?

**Is there any best practices for adding *non-bower* libraries to a bower-*esque* project?**

Comment: could you simply upload the script to a private GitHub repo and access with Bower there?

Comment: Of course not, I'm not allowed to upload licensed software to any distribution system. Also I have to deliver this project for other people to maintain, I'm interested in a logic for folder structure more than a delivery system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317105/how-to-include-a-private-local-file-in-javascript-project-using-bower has your answer.